# Why scanf scans different number than the one I enter?

Tags: c

So I'm using C for a few days and I didn't have this problem before but now I have a problem with C scanning different number than the one the user enter. I feel like it prints the location of the number but not the number itself. The number I get every time is 6422076 and if I print another number that I've scan from the user it just show the same number -4, 6422072 so I'm pretty sure It has to do with the location the computer storage the numbers.

I tried to print it with a few other ways and always get the same weird number.

```
void measures()
{
    int height;

printf("\nEnter your height:\n");
scanf("%d",&height);
while(height<140 || height>210){
    printf("Invalid input, try again: \n");
    scanf("%d",&height);
}

printf("height: %d\n",&height);
}
```

not getting any errors

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings. You should always enable warnings when compiling your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
printf("height: %d\n",&height);
```

You're not printing the value of `height`.  You're printing its **address**.  Remove the address-of operator:

```
printf("height: %d\n",height);
```

Comment: I think any IDE will warn the user about this problem.

Comment: Not everyone uses an IDE.

Comment: Any compiler will warn the user about this problem, with the `Wall` warning option. Of course, some people haven't seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Comment: @LegendofPedro I don't use an IDE but I still get compiler warnings (MSVC's default warnings).